# How to return a `forkJoin` observable when piping the operators

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngxs

Before I had this resolver that just worked fine:

```
resolve() {
    return forkJoin(
        this.getData1(),
        this.getData2(),
        this.getData3()
    );
}
```

Now I have to do something like that which is actually does not work:

```
  resolve() {
    return this.actions$
      .pipe(
        ofActionSuccessful(SomeSctonSuccess),
        forkJoin(
           this.getData1(),
           this.getData2(),
           this.getData3()
        )
      );
    }
```

as I am hitting this error:

> Argument of type 'Observable<[any, any, any, any]>' is not assignable
>   to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction'.   Type
>   'Observable<[any, any, any, any]>' provides no match for the signature
>   '(source: Observable): Observable'.

Any ideas how to fix?

Now I heed to return my `forkJoin` only after `ofActionSuccessful(SomeSctonSuccess)` is taking place https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/advanced/action-handlers

Comment: https://github.com/SrgSprinkles/AngularWeatherApp/blob/21c167e6ee0c6a29408c30d8d87def63312efb05/src/app/home/effects/dashboard.effects.ts

Comment: @Sajeetharan Thanks for pointing out to the right direction. But now after using the `exhaustMap` my component `ngOnInit` and `constructore` stop getting called? any thoughts?

Comment: can you post yout ngOnInit code?

Answer (score 4):

Use `exhaustMap` operator. It maps to inner observable, ignore other values until that observable completes

```js
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
import { exhaustMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

resolve() {
    return this.actions$
      .pipe(
        ofActionSuccessful(SomeSctonSuccess),
        exhaustMap(() => {
         return forkJoin(
             this.getData1(),
             this.getData2(),
             this.getData3()
           )
       })

      );
    }
```

Comment: that is what comment was reverencing to, I've got that by looking in to related url

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Sajeetharan by looking to this [url](https://github.com/SrgSprinkles/AngularWeatherApp/blob/21c167e6ee0c6a29408c30d8d87def63312efb05/src/app/home/effects/dashboard.effects.ts) ended up using `exhaustMap`

```
  resolve() {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
      ofActionSuccessful(LoadOnPremHostSuccess),
      exhaustMap(() => {
        return forkJoin(
          this.getData1(),
           this.getData2(),
           this.getData3()
        );
      })
    );
```

}