# How can I enforce depth-first retrieval using rxjs expand?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm working on an Angular 7 / Typescript / RxJS 6.3.3 project, using various RxJS Observables and related operators to process hierarchical collections (tree-like, specifically) of objects retrieved from a database via http server.

I thought to use the `expand` operator to create a depth-first search, and used `concatMap` to keep order... or so I hoped. Doesn't work.

See distilled example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-vf4zem

The console output from that example is:

```
dfs no delay: [1,8,9,22,23,24,2,4,7,3]
dfs with delay: [1,2,3,4,7,8,9,22,23,24]
```

(The second output line may vary depending on how much delay is added. The delay is intended to simulate data fetch from the http server.)

Given the data in the example, my desire is to consistently get the first line of output: a depth-first ordering. The key function from the example:

```
const dfs = (getter: Getter) => rootIds.pipe(
  concatMap(ids => from(ids)),
  expand(id =>
    getter(id).pipe(
      concatMap(children => from(children))
    )
  ),
  toArray()
);
```

Is there a way to enforce depth-first processing? Can `expand` not guarantee that, or is this just a poor means to accomplish getting hierarchical data into a flattened, depth-first array?

Comment: Have you tried a mix of exhaustMap and forkJoin like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50575525/how-to-return-a-forkjoin-observable-when-piping-the-operators) ?

Comment: @Wandrille I'm trying to consider how I could use something like that to accomplish what I want, but my recollection is that `exhaustMap` will ignore other values completely until the inner is finished... which means I could lose values. Not sure how to make that work as I want.

Answer (score 1):

I think its a good question and I'd agree that it seems that for parallel fetch you'll need some additional data structure to compose results after fetching.

Yet, it was interesting to implement a recursive reconstruction via `expand`, so heres my **sequential** attempt:

```ts
sequentialDFS(getChildren: Getter, ids: number[]): Observable<number[]> {
  return of(ids).pipe(
    expand(([head, ...rest]) =>
      // here we have a sequence of ids
      // that we'll explore in left-to-right order,
      // e.g. [1, 17, 20] will...
      getChildren(head).pipe(
        switchMap(subChildren => {
          // ...will turn here into [2, 6, 17, 20]
          const acc = [...subChildren, ...rest ];
          return acc.length
            ? of(acc)
            : EMPTY;
        })
      )
    ),

    // collect the heads {{{
    map(([head])=>head),
    toArray()
    // }}}
  );
}
```

* I've a bit modified the getChildren method to return `Observable<number[]>` instead of `Observable<number>`

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-rf8d1j

This is by no means an answer to the parallel fetching. Just sharing it because it was fun.

Comment: Very cool! Didn't even consider destructuring, but that works well. And the signature change of `getChildren` is fine... that's how I started, and what seems more appropriate/natural, but I was struggling a bit to get things working.

Comment: @MatthewMoss, I hope it will inspire you on writing a parallel implementation :) GL!

Comment: I'm actually re-debating whether to try and flatten the whole thing as I've attempted here, or go back to a hierarchy of list/item components, where parallelism and laziness (i.e. "performance") is almost natural.  I had reasons for trying to go this route, but I may have overestimated other difficulties and underestimated these issues.

Comment: @MatthewMoss, alas, I'm not aware of the real application of this code... I just might suggest you checking this [playground for rxjs expand](https://observable-playground.github.io/rxjs/expand/) if you'll be willing to continue with raw rxjs approach.

Comment: It's a database-driven survey builder (internal tool for client). A particular survey will have a number of top-level questions, but questions can be nested (conditionally, based on answer of parent question). Nesting can be arbitrarily deep, but probably most questions are only 0-1 deep, a few 2 deep, and rarely 3-4 deep.  The query at hand is to provide a listing of all questions in order to optionally select one to nest under while adding a new question.

BTW, that playground is awesome... Good to have more resources at hand!

Comment: I've also realized that what I want might be better as a compound database query on the server side, simplifying what the front-end has to do.

Comment: @MatthewMoss Hehe, so true! Sometimes we tend to artificially narrow the problem. And thanks for your feedback on the playground — I've been working on this pet project for a while.

Answer (score 0):

So I played around a bit, did some manual recursion (as opposed to relying on `expand`), and came up with the following (also updated at the stackblitz link above):

```
class Test {
  // This doesn't maintain depth-first order; it can vary depending on timing.
  brokenDFS(getChildren: Getter, ids: number[]): Observable<number[]> {
    return of(ids).pipe(
      concatMap(ids => from(ids)),
      expand(id => getChildren(id)),
      toArray()
    );
  }

  workingDFS(getChildren: Getter, ids: number[]): Observable<number[]> {
    return from(ids).pipe(
      concatMap(id => this.parentAndChildren(getChildren, id)),
      toArray()
    );
  }

  private parentAndChildren(getChildren: Getter, id: number): Observable<number> {
    return of(id).pipe(
      concat(
        getChildren(id).pipe(
          map(child => this.parentAndChildren(getChildren, child)),
          concatAll()
        )
      ),
    );
  }

}

const getter = getChildrenWithDelay;
const rootIds = [1, 17, 20];
const test = new Test();
test.brokenDFS(getter, rootIds).subscribe(data => console.log(`Broken: ${data}`));
test.workingDFS(getter, rootIds).subscribe(data => console.log(`Working: ${data}`));
```

The output (noting that the "Broken" output can vary due to timing):

```
Broken: 1,17,20,21,2,6,18,7,13,14,3,4,19,15,16,5,8,9,10,11,12
Working: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21
```

(Also note I changed the tree values from original post such that a correct DFS is numerical array from 1 to 21).

So `workingDFS` works, but is much slower than `brokenDFS`, since every request to the http server must wait for everything before it to complete, whereas the `brokenDFS` version would run multiple requests simultaneously (tho not in correct order).

I don't know if I have better rxjs options here. I may have to revise my methods to pass not only the objects of interest, but also some structuring/sorting info, make all/many of the requests simultaneously, and then combine everything in the correct order after.